# Spring Security no controller for login page

Tags: spring, spring-security

New at Spring Security here. I was looking at this link 'https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html#grant-access-to-remaining-resources' and got really stumped at the section **Configuring a login view controller**`.

When I'm creating a typical form, I usually make the html page that, on click, calls a method in my custom @controller, which sends to my logic, etc.

However, in their example, they state that no controller is needed because everything is 'default'. Can someone explain exactly how their login form can 'connect' to their authentication object? It looks like somehow the credentials can magically pass into the Authentication object despite having no controller method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no controller. When you use the [formLogin()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#formLogin--) method, a [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html) is registred in the [security filter chain](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/) and does the authentication job. You can look at the source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/a82cab7afdb1fc58830b1c415f1874d36b2c6c92/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java#L68):

```
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (postOnly && !request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(
                    "Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }

        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);

        if (username == null) {
            username = "";
        }

        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }

        username = username.trim();

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                username, password);

        // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
        setDetails(request, authRequest);

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take again a look into https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html#configuring-a-login-view-controller. In the code snippet you can actually see, that an internal controller with the request mapping `/login` is registered. That is why you do not have to implement it on your own. All authentication transfer between view, internal controller and the authentication manager in the background is handled completely transparent to you.